# Axios call running two times in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using Axios to fetch data from my backend. I am aware that in react, 18 strict mode components are rendered twice. And removing strict mode is bad practice because it helps you catch errors. Fetching the data twice breaks my code because I end up getting another token that does not match the one stored in my backend. Is there a way to ensure the Axios call gets called only once? Code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import history from "../../history";

class Authenticate extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           token: "",
           dataFetched: false,
       };

       this.getCallBack = this.getCallBack.bind(this);
   }
   async componentDidMount() {
       let { dataFetched } = this.state;
       if (!dataFetched) {
           try {
               await axios({
                   method: "get",
                   url: "/users/twitter_login",
               }).then((res) => {
                   if (res.data.boolean) {
                       this.setState({ dataFetched: true, token: res.data.token });
                       this.getCallBack(res.data.url);
                   } else {
                       history.push({
                           pathname: "/login",
                       });
                   }
               });
           } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
           }
       }
   }

   getCallBack(url) {
       history.push(url);
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></img>
           </div>
       );
   }
}

export default Authenticate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom hook or it's equivelent in class land

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
const useInit = (effect: () => void ) => {
    const ref = useRef(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) return
        ref.current = true
        effect?.()
    },[])
}
export default useInit
```